# Vertical align when td contains image or text

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my problem. I am able to `vertical center` all content except when there is no image and there is text shown. The text `Antec Leyden b.v.` is not shown in the middle

[image]

I have tried different codes, all with the same result.

1.

```
if(!empty($find_logo[0])) { echo '<td><img src="'.$find_logo[0].'" height="35"/></td>'; } else { echo '<td style="vertical-align:middle">'.$row_table_1['leverancier'].'</td>'; }
```

2.

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle">'; if(!empty($find_logo[0])) { echo '<img src="'.$find_logo[0].'" height="35"/>'; } else { echo $row_table_1['leverancier']; } echo '</td>
```

3.

```
<td>'; if(!empty($find_logo[0])) { echo '<img src="'.$find_logo[0].'" height="35"/>'; } else { echo '<span style="vertical-align:middle">'.$row_table_1['leverancier'].'</span>'; } echo '</td>
```

Here is my original table

```
echo'
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">'; if(!empty($find_image[0])) { echo '<img src="'.$find_image[0].'" height="35"/>'; } echo '</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">'; if(($row_table_1['aantal_huidig'] < $row_table_1['aantal_min_1']) && $row_table_1['in_bestelling'] == 0) { echo '<span style="color:#DC3545 !important;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span> '; }
               elseif(($row_table_1['aantal_huidig'] < $row_table_1['aantal_min_2']) && $row_table_1['in_bestelling'] == 0) { echo '<span style="color:#FFC107 !important;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span> '; }
               echo $row_table_1['artikelnr'].'</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">'.$row_table_1['omschrijving'].'</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle">'.$row_table_1['groep'].'</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle" align="center">'; if($row_table_1['aantal_huidig'] > 0) { echo $row_table_1['aantal_huidig']; } echo '</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle" align="center">'; if($row_table_1['in_bestelling'] > 0) { echo $row_table_1['in_bestelling']; } echo '</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle" align="center">'; if($row_table_1['bestelhoeveelheid'] > 0) { echo $row_table_1['bestelhoeveelheid']; } echo '</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle" align="center">'; if($row_table_1['aantal_huidig'] < $row_table_1['aantal_min_1'] && $row_table_1['in_bestelling'] == 0) { echo '<a href="#"><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_add_mag_table_1'.$i.'" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Maak bestelling"></span></a>'; } echo '</td>
        <td>'; if(!empty($find_logo[0])) { echo '<img src="'.$find_logo[0].'" height="35"/>'; } else { echo $row_table_1['leverancier']; } echo '</td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle" class="text-center"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_edit_table_2'.$i.'" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Bewerk"></span></a> <a href="magazijn_label.php?id='.$row_table_1['id'].'" target="_blank"><span class="fas fa-tag" title="Print label"></span></a></td>
    </tr>';
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: so you are saying that your method doesn't align the text vertically?

Comment: Give line-height to the text

Comment: can you share publish code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use:

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle">'; if(!empty($find_logo[0])) { echo '<img src="'.$find_logo[0].'" height="35"/>'; } else { echo $row_table_1['leverancier']; } echo '</td>
   |------------------------------|
```

You didn't add that even though it's in all the other `<td>`s.

---

Alternatively, since you know that the image height is `height="35"` (as per your code), then apply `line-height: 35px;` (CSS) for that cell. Using line-height is a commonly accepted practise to centre text vertically when they're in a single line, but if the height is not known in advance then it doesn't work as well.

Comment: `style="line-height:35px;"` was the solution.